# web based images not working in toast created by @nodert-win10/windows.ui.notifications

Tags: node.js, windows, notifications, electron

I am trying to show an image from the web but it isn't working.
In following code works only local image.

```
const { XmlDocument } = require('@nodert-win10/windows.data.xml.dom');
const {
  ToastNotification,
  ToastNotificationManager
} = require('@nodert-win10/windows.ui.notifications');
const path = require('path');

const localImage = path.join(__dirname, 'image.jpg');
const webImage = 'http://picsum.photos/360/202?image=11';
const template = `
  <toast launch="app-defined-string">
    <visual>
      <binding template="ToastGeneric">
        <image id="1" placement="appLogoOverride" hint-crop="circle" src="${localImage}"/>
        <image id="2" placement="hero" src="${webImage}"/>
      </binding>
    </visual>
  </toast>
`;

const xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.loadXml(template);

const toast = new ToastNotification(xml);
const notifier = ToastNotificationManager.createToastNotifier(appId);

notifier.show(toast);
```

Is there any chance to get Windows 10 Toast notification created from an electron app works with web images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. It's not cause of Electron, underlying toastnotification api doesn't accept non local source images. MSDN documentation is bit hard to track this information as most cases ToastNotification is used in UWP apps. If you are publishing app as UWP and uses UWP api, it'll work to point remote image resources.